# PhantomJS / CasperJS Canvas selector

Tags: html, canvas, selector, phantomjs, casperjs

Using PhantomJS V 1.8.1

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to run some tests on a website that I am developing which is using backbone.js.

One of my tests involve checking to see if a Canvas is present and clicking on it. My problem is that whatever selector I use to get the Canvas Element I cannot get the selector to find it. I use the same CSS selector in Google Chrome when viewing the page and all is OK. At first I thought that the issue may have been due to the element not being present on the page but other elements which are inserted with the canvas are present so I am 99% sure that this is not the problem.

The selectors I have tried to use are:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#idOfCanvas');

document.querySelectorAll('canvas#idOfCanvas');
```

Also if I use `.classClassName:nth(1)` to select the tyre selector, it still fails to work (works in Google Chrome though as does the other examples provided)

The canvas has a class name which is picked up by the selector by I would rather not use a class selector.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers :)

Also

Like I mentioned I am almost certain that the Canvas exists as the container div for it exists. Also I have four elements on the page with the same className (two of which are canvases) and four elements are being returned when I run

return document.querySelectorAll('.className').length = 4;

Comment: Just tried "this.echo(this.getHTML('#canvasWrapperDiv'));" and nothing was returned suggesting that the canvas is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
<canvas id="idOfCanvas"></canvas>
```

This should work:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("idOfCanvas");
// or
canvas = document.querySelector("#idOfCanvas"); // Only get the first match, ID's should be unique, any way.;
// or
canvas = document.querySelectorAll("#idOfCanvas")[0];
// or
canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]; // Get the first <canvas> element.
```

However,  you'll have to make sure your canvas element is actually loaded when the script is executed. Have a look at [this `onload` tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded), for example.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
canvas = document.getElementById(#IdOfCanvas:nth-child(1));
```